# How to test Laravel Apiato API with Postman?

Tags: apiato

Please, I need help.
I am beginner to apiato, I followed these instructions: "https://apiato.io/docs/9.x/miscellaneous/postman/#apiato-postman-api--environment" to test my API on postman, but I have a problem acces to API endpoint. Here is what postman shows me: "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.apiato.test"

I use VScode as editor and Laragon

I followed these instructions: "https://apiato.io/docs/9.x/miscellaneous/postman/#apiato-postman-api--environment" to test my API on postman, but I have a problem acces to API endpoint. Here is what postman shows me: "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.apiato.test"

I use VScode as editor and Laragon

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the solution, but the creator has a postman collection you can import, the login is outdated and some other api links may be as well.  Login should be this v1/clients/web/login.

If you look at version 9 on the docs under Miscellaneous there is a nice postman collection for testing your api.  I also found a nice package to generate new postman requests from your current api.  For creating a current postman api I just imported the environment from version 9 docs. Then I added a variable called base_url it is same as the domain variable.  After installing the package, I ran    php artisan export:postman --bearer="your token" then just opened the generated file and copied and pasted the json into the Import function of Postman.  Here is the package on github https://github.com/andreaselia/laravel-api-to-postman  Cheers!

Oh, I just realized you found the postman collection, but as I said some of it is outdated for version 11.

One other thing to check.  In postman the default Accept header was * / * I had to disable this header and add a new Accept application/json header

One other thing, make sure this works, open your browser and goto http://api.apiato.test/v1 You should see a JSON response with message: "Welcome to apiato (API V1)."   Also, if your server is using a port make sure you add that to your base_url or domain in post man.  Example mine is
http://api.apiato.test:8000.  Also make sure you update your host file according to the docs.

One more thing you need for postman to work with your new collection.

Add this to your login under Tests.

if (responseCode.code === 200) {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", jsonData.access_token);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("expires_in", jsonData.expires_in);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("refresh_token", jsonData.refresh_token);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token_type", jsonData.token_type);
}

Add this to your logout under Tests.

if (responseCode.code === 202) {
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", "");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("expires_in", "");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("refresh_token", "");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token_type", "");
}

Then click on your collection and under Authorization change type to Bearer token and set the Token to {{access_token}}